# MSSQL sequelize отображает только найденные строки

Tags: javascript, sql-server, sequelize.js

В таблице `[realizations]`

```
[id],[label],[vendor]
```

имеется перечень товара

Таблица `[prices]`

```
[id],[price],[realizationId],[organizationId]
```

предназначена для занесения цен по каждому товару и по каждой организации

в контроллере выполняю поиск и вывод всех позиций `[realizations]`, а также поиск в `[prices]` для отображения цен по организации

```js
include: [
 {
  model: Price,
  as: 'price',
  where: {
   organizationId: organizationId,
  },
 }
]
```

на странице `index` отображаю таблицу с перечнем `[realizations]` и соответствующих цен для организации из `[prices]`

но она отображает только те позиции, которые присутствуют в `[prices]`, а необходимо чтобы отображала весь перечень из `[realizations]`. И для позиций, которых нет в `[prices]`, ничего не отображала для ячейке `price`

подскажите пожалуйста, как правильно сделать запрос в контроллере

Answer (score 0):

ответ найден

```js
include: [
           {
               model: Price,
               as: 'price',
               where: {
                 organizationId: organizationId,
              },
              required: false
           }
]
```